# How the internal pipes in linux work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I do ps , ps will show that in the list.
But when I do ps | grep hello even though ps is the process , grep is the process shown.
Is it that pipes work that way ?
How is the pipe read fd closed automatically ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even though ps is the process , grep is the process shown

Both `ps` **and** `grep` are processes. You just don't see the `ps` line because it does not have "hello" in it. Try, for example, `ps | grep ".*"` instead, or even `ps | sort | tac | shuf`.

In other words, you have:

- Process 1: `ps aux`

  - Fd 0 (stdin): terminal (/dev/tty)
  - Fd 1 (stdout): anonymous pipe (→write)
  - Fd 2 (stderr): terminal
- Process 2: `grep hello`

  - Fd 0 (stdin): anonymous pipe (read→)
  - Fd 1 (stdout): terminal
  - Fd 2 (stderr): terminal

running **at the same time**.

---

Here's another interesting test – ask `ls` to show its own file descriptors:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd | cat
lrwx------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:29 0 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:29 1 -> pipe:[8087631]
lrwx------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:29 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:29 3 -> /proc/2150013/fd/

$ echo test | ls -l /proc/self/fd
lr-x------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:29 0 -> pipe:[8086629]
lrwx------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:29 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:29 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:29 3 -> /proc/2150022/fd/

$ echo test | ls -l /proc/self/fd | cat
lr-x------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:30 0 -> pipe:[8088183]
l-wx------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:30 1 -> pipe:[8088184]
lrwx------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:30 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 64 Jul 31 14:30 3 -> /proc/2150056/fd/
```